# How do I disable warnings from Aspx files (HTML,CSS)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, css, visual-studio-2008

All my aspx files give all kinds of annoying warnings like "The CSS Value is not defined" because I'm referencing CSS files from other projects relative to where they will be published in IIS.  And other things I ignore like "Zoom is not a valid css property" even though I need it to fix crappy IE 6 rendering bugs.

I tried adding `WarningLevel="0"` to the `<%@ Page` tag but I'm still getting warnings.  I still want to receive warnings from my code behind file I just don't care for the HTML, CSS and Javascript warnings.

Anybody know how to do this.  I would also be interested in disabling specific warnings.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzzzth4.aspx

Also try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzzzth4.aspx

Finally the best thing to try is

http://neilkilbride.blogspot.com/2007/10/visual-studio-error-list-html-errors.html

Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Validation > Show errors

Answer (score 1):

Go to Options -> HTML -> Validation

Uncheck 'Show Errors'.

Comment: thanx - this has been bugging me for ages

Comment: For VS 2008:

Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Validation

Uncheck 'Show Errors'

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/18/vs-2008-support-to-treat-html-css-and-jscript-validation-issues-as-warnings-instead-of-errors.aspx